# SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer does not display screen buffer

Tags: c#, winapi, console-application

I am currently trying to write a console application in C# with two screen buffers, which should be swapped back and forth (much like VSync on a modern GPU). Since the `System.Console` class does not provide a way to switch buffers, I had to P/Invoke several methods from kernel32.dll.

This is my current code, grossly simplified:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr oldBuffer = GetStdHandle(-11); //Gets the handle for the default console buffer
    IntPtr newBuffer = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(0, 0x00000001, IntPtr.Zero, 1, 0); //Creates a new console buffer

    /* Write data to newBuffer */

    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(newBuffer);
}
```

The following things occured:

- The screen remains empty, even though it should be displaying `newBuffer`
- When written to `oldBuffer` instead of `newBuffer`, the data appears immediately. Thus, my way of writing into the buffer should be correct.
- Upon calling `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(newBuffer)`, the error code is now 6, which means invalid handle. This is strange, as the handle is not -1, which the documentation discribes as invalid.

I should note that I very rarely worked with the Win32 API directly and have very little understanding of common Win32-related problems. I would appreciate any sort of help.

Comment: Do **not** call `GetLastError` unless **explicitly** asked to do so. See this [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/winapi/2573/error-reporting-and-handling/8521/error-reported-with-additional-information-on-failure#t=201609121054592086284) for more information. When done reading, update your question.

Comment: Alright, but this does not really change the entire question all too much. The main point is that setting a buffer does not work and I do not understand why.

Comment: You can at least remove the redundant observations from the *"things occurred"* list. There is no merit in explicitly pointing out that the observed behavior matches the documented behavior.

Comment: I removed the one regarding getting the current console buffer, but I'm keeping the second one because I believe the call fails there

Comment: Programming isn't about guessing. You determine whether the call failed by evaluating its return value, as explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686010.aspx): *"If the function fails, the return value is zero."* Your code doesn't check the return value.

Comment: Yes, my return value is false, indicating a problem. I know that it fails, I just don't know why. Specifically, I don't know why it returns "Invalid Handle"

Comment: It fails, because you pass in an invalid handle. You aren't checking the return value for [`CreateConsoleScreenBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682122.aspx), and passing 0 for the *dwDesiredAccess* doesn't appear to be correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As IInspectable points out in the comments, you're setting `dwDesiredAccess` to zero.  That gives you a handle with no access permissions.  There are some edge cases where such a handle is useful, but this isn't one of them.

The only slight oddity is that you're getting "invalid handle" rather than "access denied".  I'm guessing you're running Windows 7, so the handle is a user-mode object (a "pseudohandle") rather than a kernel handle.

At any rate, you need to set `dwDesiredAccess` to `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE` as shown [in the sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685032.aspx).

---

Also, as Hans pointed out in the comments, the declaration on pinvoke.net was incorrect, specifying the last argument as a four-byte integer rather than a pointer-sized integer.  I believe the correct declaration is

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
    uint dwDesiredAccess,
    uint dwShareMode, 
    IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, 
    uint dwFlags,
    IntPtr lpScreenBufferData
    );
```

Comment: The [DllImport] declaration can't be correct either, last argument is IntPtr.

Comment: This is probably caused by the code on pinvoke.net, which is inarguably wrong.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, it is. I saw several people here mention pinvoke.net, so I assumed it had some credibility

Comment: I've edited the page on pinvoke.net, hope I got it right. :-)