# Text Adventure: Issue with main not allowing re-input of name after attempting to reset character

Tags: c++, string

I'm attempting to code a text-based game in C++ for a school project. Sparing unimportant details, I have a character creator that has the user input name and stats, as well as a 'reset character' option that allows the player to start back from the beginning. Here are the important parts of the code so far.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int charCreator();

string cmd, cmd2, name = "name";

int main()
{
    cin >> cmd;
    if(cmd == "reset"){
        while(cmd == "reset"){
            cout << "Enter your character's name to reset.\n";
            cin >> cmd2;
            if(cmd2 == name){
                cout << name << " is sent screaming into the dark abyss. A new challenger approaches.\n";
                charCreator();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//function for character creation
int charCreator()
{
    cout << "Name: ";
    getline(cin, name);

    cout << "\nWelcome, " << name << "!\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

What *should* happen is that the player 'resets' their character, turning all values to their default values, including `name`, but when you reset it skips the name input and leaves it blank. What I want to know is why this is happening and how I can fix it.

EDIT: Changing `getline(cin, name)` to `cin >> name` seems to have fixed the problem. New question: Is there any way to have `getline()` in `charCreator()` so that it doesn't produce this problem?

Comment: If you have to prepend your question with "Sorry if this is vague", then you can almost be certain that you are about to ask a bad question. Without even looking at it, I can already tell it's much too long, has far too much code and likely asks far more than one question in the body. I **highly** recommend you to read the [ask] page and then change your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will attempt to shorten the question.

Comment: I'd suggest you to think about one specific problem you have and then write a minimal example that shows your problem. From the title alone, I can see you have problems getting user input again after some event, yet your code includes cruft like `levelUp()`, character creation and what not. All of this is completely irrelevant to the question at hand. Just to give you an idea of formatting, here is [a question I have written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443342/setconsoleactivescreenbuffer-does-not-display-screen-buffer) with similar scope of problems.

Comment: Also, "reducing your code to a minimal format" does not mean "just cut some lines away." I mean create a [mcve], with the emphasis on **complete**.